# Does $E(X_1) \leq E(X_2)$ implies $E(f(X_1)) \leq E(f(X_2))$ for a monotone increasing function $f\colon R \mapsto R^{+}$?

Tags: statistics

For two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$, does $\mathrm{E}(X_1) \leq \mathrm{E}(X_2)$ implies $\mathrm{E}(f(X_1)) \leq \mathrm{E}(f(X_2))$ for a monotone increasing function $f\colon \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{+}$?

In particular, we know that in maximum likelihood estimation, $\mathrm{E}(\log f(Z; \theta)) \leq \mathrm{E}(\log f(Z; \theta_0))$ by the Jensen's inequality. Here $f(Z;\theta)$ is a density function parameterized by $\theta$, and $\theta_0$ is the true value of $\theta$. I would expect $\mathrm{E}(f(Z; \theta)) \leq \mathrm{E}(f(Z; \theta_0))$. Otherwise, it would be weird that there exists a $\theta^*$ such that $\mathrm{E}(f(Z; \theta^*)) > \mathrm{E}(f(Z; \theta_0))$.

Comment: Related to [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/64431/6633) on stats.SE where additional conditions were imposed ($f$ is concave, random variables are discrete) and the answer was No, the implication is not valid.

Comment: Good to know, thanks.

Comment: In fact, the definition of convexity shows that whenever $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is not convex, it is possible to find discrete random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ with $X_1$ constant a.e., $\mathbb E(X_1)=\mathbb E(X_2)$ and $\mathbb E(X_2)<\mathbb E(X_1)$. Just take $u<v$ and $\lambda\in [0,1]$ with $f((1-\lambda) u+\lambda v)>(1-\lambda )f(u)+\lambda f(v)$ and define $X_1$ to be $(1-\lambda) u+\lambda v$ a.e. and $X_2$ to be $u$ with probability $(1-\lambda)$ and $v$ with probability $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x^2+1$ for nonnegative $X$ (extended arbitrarily for negative $x$ subject to being increasing and positive).  Let $X_1$ have value $0$ with probability $2/3$ and value $2$ with probability $1/3$.  So $E(X_1)=2/3$ and $E({X_1}^2+1)=7/3$ Let $X_2$ have value $1$ with probability $1$. So $E(X_2)=1$ and $E({X_2}^2+1)=2$.   Thus, $E(X_1)<E(X_2)$ but $E(f(X_1))>E(f(X_2))$.

Answer (score 1):

The implication does not hold true. For example, define $X_1$ and $X_2$ on $[0,1]$ (with Lebesgue measure) by $X_1(t)=1$ and $X_2(t)=\alpha t$ where $2<\alpha<e$, and take $f(x)=x^{1/n}$ where $n$ is a large integer (with $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$). Then $\mathbb E(X_1)=1<\frac\alpha2=\mathbb E(X_2)$, whereas $\mathbb E(f(X_1))=1>\mathbb E(f(X_2))=\frac{n}{n+1}\alpha^{1/n}$ if $n$ is large enough because $\alpha<e$. Indeed, $\frac{n}{n+1}\alpha^{1/n}$ holds iff $\alpha <\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$, and this is true if $n$ is large enough because $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\to e$ as $n\to\infty$.

This example is certainly not the simplest possible one!